# How can I apply a stylesheet to only my jquery datepicker widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My main page is controlled by a tab-type widget and I have a stylesheet that is specifically designed for this.  However, I just recently realized that I need a datepicker in my application as well.  I've added the `jquery-ui-style.cs` stylesheet to my project. The problem is that I only want this stylesheet to affect my datepicker and not my tabs.

Is there a way to apply this stylesheet only to my datepicker either when the page initially loads or whenever the textbox is focused on?

It's probably not needed but here is my jquery for the datepicker:

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtViewWeeksData").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
    });
});
```

Comment: In a few years the answer to this will be easy, `<style scoped="true">..` unfortunately, right now you are stuck with using a class or similar to scope it. :(

Comment: Seems tricky, you can only add an outerscope, currently in the Themeroller/download. So you would have to edit the CSS, and then in the jquery add/remove it on beforeshow/close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly there is no "easy" way.

But i made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ggwGs/9/

On the download page (http://jqueryui.com/download) you can under "Theme" select "Advanced". Where you can create an custom "CSS Scope", enter and special theme name, example ".customTheme" and press donnload.

If you have created a custom theme, you do exactly the same under "**Download Theme**".

Now we need to add the CSS scope class to the Datepicker when active, and remove when not.

So we do it like this:

```
$("#txtViewWeeksData").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {$(inst.dpDiv).addClass('customTheme');},
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {$(inst.dpDiv).removeClass('customTheme');}
});
```

Basicly we tell it that right before showing add the scope, and right after it's closed remove it again.